# What does it mean hlines in org's table?

Tags: org-mode

Emacs 26.1.
In my org file I has table.

[image]

As you can see in table formula I has:

```
@>$6 = vsum(@I..@II)
```

This mean:

```
Last row and column#6 = sum of all rows between first and second hline
```

The question is:

What does it mean `hline` in org's table?

This is all rows that start by symbol `#`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hline** is short for **horizontal separator line**. Please read the manual:

https://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-Table-Editor.html

Comment: To be fair, the manual page linked to starts off by calling them "horizontal rules" and describes "header lines", which could easily be confused for hlines. The places buried further down the page where the phrase "horizontal separator lines" are introduced don't correlate to actions with "hline" in their name, and the actions that do include "hline" use just "horizontal line", so the manual could be clearer in indicating that hline corresponds to the type of row it starts off calling "horizontal rules"... the ones with the dashes in them.